# Wordpress asigning product to user to show report

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

### Wordpress, Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), Woocommerce

Hello,

currently I am working on project that is needed to manage **products (Music artists)** and **customers (bars/lounges)**.

I need to solve the communication between "artist(product) being booked/purchased as product by bar/lounge(customer)" in Woocommerce.

Artists must be able to login and see if they have been booked by customer and the additional information must be shown (who is the customer (bar or lounge name), place, when, how long, must take his equipment or not).

I am thinking of asigning **product id(artist)** to **user role - artist**.
User login is generated manualy by administrator.

Artist logins by the credentials given by administrator and is able to see his own **report** of the information that must be shown.

[Advanced custom fields custom user role and post type as woocommerce product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C104T.png)

Is there any possiblity lets say for the purchase that is finished to be displayed not only for administrator but for user "Artist".

I am thinking of editing **wp-admin/profile.php** , but is it the correct way of doing it?

---

*I will try updating the solution where I have gone so far, as soon as there will be new information.*

Comment: Yes I understand the there will be needed much more.
In this case let's just display order information of unique product for user backend. But is it the correct way just making everything in functions.php @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 0):

You can add artists as vendor's, and with same name product. Now assign that product to that vendor. Whenever his product is bought he will get notification and can see stats also. As he can log in to dashboard with some restricted access. Many vendor plugins are there in market. I am giving you a sample one :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-vendors/

Comment: Thank you. This plugin really helped me alot. The only problem I am facing right now is rights for vendors to be restricted (like editing the product). Should I find it somewhere in plugin or in wordpress dashboard? @mickey

Comment: There is another plugin named Advance Access Manager, install it to customize user access. You can upvote the answer if that helps :)